# Streaming de vídeo com C#

Tags: c#

Preciso criar uma aplicação que irá receber streaming de vídeo de várias câmeras em tempo real, como em um painel de segurança onde se pode monitorar o que acontece através das câmeras (como em um sistema de vigilância). Para isso pretendo usar C#, já fiz algo parecido mas em outra linguagem e usei FFmpeg.

Em questão de performance, este recurso é o ideal? Ele tem compatibilidade com C#? Existem projetos que usam e tem bom funcionamento? Caso não seja, o que me recomendam usar? Se C# não for uma boa opção, qual linguagem me recomendam?

---

**Edit 1:** A prioridade do projeto é a **performance**.

**Edit 2:** Posteriormente serão adicionadas funcionalidades como pausar, voltar e continuar o vídeo dentro do próprio software. Também monitoramento de imagens, como por exemplo: emitir um alerta visual e sonoro quando houver movimentação em alguma câmera. 
Estas são apenas algumas das funcionalidades para ajudar a entender melhor aplicação e sua necessidade de ter uma boa performance.

Comment: Você pretende apenas exibir em vários players o conteúdo de diversas fontes ou receber e redistribuir para outros clients? Já trabalhei muito com soluções de video em C# e FFmpeg, mas não entendi a aplicação dele nesse contexto.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Preciso apenas exibir o streaming de vídeo de diversas fontes em um painel. Como se fosse um grid, com nove players recebendo as imagens.

Comment: Então não tem muito mistério não, cabe a você definir de acordo com o ambiente e seu conforto, o tipo de aplicação vai desenvolver (WindowsForms, WPF, UWP ou WebApp). Depois, se aparecer algum problema você retorna aqui e a gente ajuda a resolver esse ponto específico

Comment: não entendi, qual é a sua dúvida específica? você está oferecendo a recompensa para que alguém construa essa solução para você?

Comment: É óbvio que não quero que construam uma aplicação pra mim. Procurava um conselho de pessoas mais experientes que pudesse me nortear na construção da mesma. Se não pode ajudar, obrigado assim mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Sem um contexto é difícil dar uma sugestão porque pode estar a tentar fazer uma aplicação [UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide), [WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/index) ou *web*.

Assumindo que está a tentar fazer uma aplicação WPF eu recomendaria dar uma olhada à [wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Main_Page/) do [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), já que eles têm uma entrada dedicada à [integração do VLC com aplicações desenvolvidas em C#](https://wiki.videolan.org/C_Sharp/) e parece ser um ótimo bom de partida.

Existem mais algumas alternativas mas pelo que vi muitas delas não recebem atualizações há anos. Pelo menos recorrendo a bibliotecas baseadas no VLC existirá sempre algum suporte pois o VLC é um dos *softwares* que *nunca* irá deixar de existir.

---

Pode também ver exemplos da Microsoft em como consumir um stream numa [aplicação UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming) ou numa [aplicação WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/885869/Stream-Player-control) com recurso ao [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) uma vez que já trabalhou com ele.

Comment: A aplicação ainda não começou a ser desenvolvida, amigo. Estou estudando e procurando material para escolher um bom caminho pensando na performance da mesma. Se vai ser UWP ou WPF eu ainda não sei porque não sei qual dos dois traria mais qualidade, mas web não será. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Tenha em mente que UWP só corre em Windows 10 e apenas corre nas versões para  qual faz _target_. Não sei o contexto da sua organização mas nem todas têm Windows 10 implantado a 100%. WFP não será uma má aposta se quiser zelar pela retro-compatibilidade.

Comment: Entendi, então é melhor usar WFP porque jamais terei controle de onde a aplicação vai rodar. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.